# Monitoring tcp port using google app script

Tags: networking, google-apps-script

How can I monitor (if is open) TCP port using google app script eg. telnet host_name port? I tried use UrlFetchApp.fetch method but I think it is the wrong way...

Comment: Define "open"... what are you trying to accomplish in the big picture?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't provide any Services for that kind of a task.

Comment: UrlFetch uses http. Different port than ftp.